# How do I use "It's none of your business"?

Tags: slang

I don't know how to use the phrase "it's none of your business" in everyday English or slang, please help me?

Comment: Also see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/567155/can-i-use-whats-it-to-you-for-its-none-of-your-business

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"it’s none of your business" is slightly rude when said directly to the person. Just use it when you want to tell it to maybe a close friend? Or some stranger who was rude to you, also "mind your own business" has the similar situation and is slightly rude as well.

If you want to be more polite and diplomatic you could use “I’d rather not talk about that,” or “I’m not comfortable sharing that information.”

Comment: So far as I'm concerned, *It’s none of your business* and *Mind your own business* are almost always *incredibly* rude (often almost on a par with *Fuck off!* for people who don't swear much). And that's even compared to *It doesn't concern you*, which is *usually* hostile / dismissive / rude.